# jQuery validation - how to remove common message

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I made common validation message ("You have errors on page") using "invalidHandler" option.
Now I'm looking for a way to remove this message (on leave control) when all the fields will become valid.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? That you don't know how to remove an element or how to detect whether all fields are valid?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what triggers when all fields become valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `invalidHandler` is one way to do this, but if you use the `errorContainer` option, jQuery validate will take care of hiding and showing the message for you. For example:

**Html:**

```
<form id="test">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="required"/>

    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input id="age" type="text" name="age" class="required"/>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<div id="invalid">You have errors the on page</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#invalid { display: none; }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#test").validate({
    errorContainer: "#invalid"
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/deArQ/

Comment: Great, this solution solves the problem, yet I wonder if there is an event that gets fired only after all validations are passed.

Comment: Hmmm, yes but no, submitHandler will fire when the form tries to be submitted. But the fields are validated 'on change' and it is possible that all fields validate successfully before the submitHandler is executed. So, that is the event that we are looking for: something that will trigger when the errorContainer gets hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The invalidHandler option over rides the internal plugin error handling that adds and removes errors automatically. If all you are doing is setting the message in the option, you would do better removing the option.

The plugin is so flexible that to a certain degree it depends on what you are asking of the invalidHandler and the behavior s you want from your validation process

You can override the default messages this way

```
$.validator.messages.required='My Required message';
```

Comment: Isn't that about "required" case only? What about general mesage for "required" rules, other built-in rules plus custom rules? invalidHandler isn't called when I tab over fields.

Comment: what I showed is changing the default for "required" if you never set it in options. Most people use the "messages" option to set messages

Comment: very hard to provide much more info without seeing some code that you could edit to original post